# Is there a way I can write my PHP code for WordPress a bit more optimized? Right now I feel like there could be a better way

Tags: php, wordpress, optimization

So I am writing a template file for WordPress and I feel like I am using too many echo tabs. Just wanted to see if there is something that is better and easier that I am not doing right now.

```
<h1>Responsive grid layout</h1>
      <dl class="gridtab-1">

        <?php 
            $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 5 );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
              echo '<dt>', the_post_thumbnail('medium'), '</dt>';
              echo '<dd class="entry-content">';

              echo '<div class="bdanzer-container">', 
                        '<div class="bdanzer-left">';

                            echo '<p>', the_post_thumbnail('large'), '</p>';

                        echo '</div>';

                echo '<div class="bdanzer-right">';
                    echo '<h1>', the_title() , '</h1>';
                    echo '<p>',the_content(),'</p>';
                echo '</div>';

                echo '<p>', the_category(), '</p>';

              echo '</div>';
              echo '</dd>';


            endwhile;
        ?>

        </dl>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a **code review request**. This might be better suited to the [Code Review Stack Exchange site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). Before posting there be sure to read their [FAQ](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) to ensure that your question meets their guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be something like this:

```
<h1>Responsive grid layout</h1>
<dl class="gridtab-1">
<?php 
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 5 );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
    <dt><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?></dt>
    <dd class="entry-content">
        <div class="bdanzer-container">
            <div class="bdanzer-left">
                <p><?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="bdanzer-right">
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
            </div>
            <p><?php the_category(); ?></p>
        </div>
    </dd>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</dl>
```

Just close the `php` tag and start using plain html, use `php` only when is needed.

Comment: Yeah that makes a lot more sense. Not sure why I didn't do what you have haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use separate class for code and template for view.